# Replace only one nested block in twig

Tags: php, templates, twig, extending

I have the following twig structure:

**base.twig**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body class="fade-in {{body_class}}">
    <main>
      {% block menu %}
          {% include 'menu.twig' %}
      {% endblock %}
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

**menu.twig**

```
<header>
  <div>
    {% block menu_main %}
       {% include 'menu-main.twig' %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block menu_country %}
        {% include 'menu-country.twig' with { menu_country: dropdownland } %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</header>
```

**child.twig**

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block menu %}
  {% block menu_country %}
    {% include 'menu-country.twig' with { menu_country: menu_ap_countries } %}
  {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

What i want to achieve is, just replace the block **menu_country** inside child.twig. If i use the approach above, the whole block **menu** gets replaced by only **menu_country** which means that the block **menu_main** is missing.

I tried also

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block menu %}
  {{ parent() }}
  {% block menu_country %}
    {% include 'menu-country.twig' with { menu_country: menu_ap_countries } %}
  {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

but this renders the block **menu_country** twice. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further investigation due to @DarkBees answer, i came accross the **embed** function which does exactly what i need in this case. So the extending template becomes this:

```
{% block menu %}
  {% embed 'menu.twig'%}
    {% block menu_country %}
      {% include 'menu-country.twig' with { menu_country: menu_ap_countries } %}
    {% endblock %}
  {% endembed %}
{% endblock %}
```

By embedding, I am able to overwrite the block inside `menu.twig`

Answer (score 0):

Including templates does not mean u are importing said blocks inside the template.
This mean only the block `menu` will exists inside `child.twig`.

In your first example you are actually just overwriting the block `menu` and creating a new block `menu_country` inside of it.

In your second example, you are telling `twig` to output the default content of the block `menu` and append a new block `menu_country` to it.

---

A possible solution would be to change set-up to this e.g.

*menu.twig*

```html
<header>
  <div>
    {% block menu_main %}
       {% include 'menu-main.twig' %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block menu_country %}
        {% include 'menu-country.twig' %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</header>
```

*menu-country.twig*

```html
<ul class="country">
{% for country in menu_country|default(dropdownland) %}
    <li><a href="#">{{ country }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

*child.twig*

```html
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block menu %}
    {% include 'menu.twig' with { menu_country: menu_ap_countries, } %}
{% endblock %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/yt0jc1/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. Indeed it clarified some things, but i found a more proper may to solve this for my case. Embed was the keyword.